# git-svn -- Why are other branches' commits mixed in with trunk commits on master?

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-svn, git-log

I'm tracking a svn repository using git. A merge was done on 2014-01-09 (producing commit `A`) and another on 2014-02-12 (producing commit `B`). When I `git checkout master; git log`, I see the commits for the merges, but I also see, for instance, a commit on 2014-02-04 (`C`) made against a branch (which was merged as part of `B`).

**Why would a commit made against a branch show up when running `git log` on trunk ?**

I discovered this while trying to rewind my master and branches to a particular date in time to try to execute merge `B` again to see what conflicts exist. I had assumed that I could `git checkout master; git reset --hard B^; git merge branch;`, but that didn't work, then I saw these extra commits from branches in my trunk log and got confused.

Any help you can offer on the subject will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `C` is part of a branch that was merged into `master` to produce `B`, then a `git log` on `master` will include all commits that were in the branch, including `C`. This is expected behavior, and necessary to understand all the individual commits that are a part of `master`. There may be a flag to `git log` to hide commits that also appear in different branch, but I can't find such a mechanism.

Comment: `--first-parent`, which doesn't trace commits only included by merging another branch into the current one.  it's not perfect, though, because git fundamentally doesn't have a concept of which branch a commit was made on.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I hadn't realized git-svn was so smart. I long ago noticed that when I `git svn clone`ed, `git log --oneline --graph` didn't track branches properly. "Oh well", I said, "better than nothing." I didn't realize that a later `git svn rebase`, etc., *does* track branches correctly! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I originally thought you meant that the merge occurred on the `git` side of things, and after I realized you meant it occurred on the `svn` side, I've begun to second-guess my answer. I couldn't find any references that give me a clear answer. It does seem like `git` would have to be awfully smart to translate an `svn` merge into a `git` merge, since they are very different concepts. I can't figure out what else would be happening, though.